# Divide by zero error unique zeros

Tags: t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Item         Ordqty Total_Costprice TotalSaleprice  onhand  Markup
ENG-MAN-0102                3852    203.34           2494     73.992
SPG-P-018                   2716   1232.80      473.2232
A8                          8.62    9.335                    0.71
A136                        1621    148.35           518    0.3777
LA                  1228    7.68    14.897                   7.217
ENG-DOR             1039    34.94   50.8166                15.8766
A13-00-S               968  153.64    107                   0.9997​
```

Code is

```
SELECT
    total_costprice, 
    markup,
    CASE WHEN markup=0 THEN 0 ELSE 100*(markup)/costprice AS pctmarkup`
```

This gives a divide by zero error. I need to show the percentage markup for the markup values.

Comment: You would get a syntax error with that code before you got a divide by 0 error

Comment: You want to check if your denominator is a 0 before dividing, not your numerator. `CASE WHEN costprice = 0 THEN 0 ELSE... `

Comment: What do you do when you dont have any values?

Comment: `costprice` or `total_costprice` ?

Comment: Regarding your syntax error, you need an `END` to conclude your CASE statement. I would also change your percentage formula to put your division inside of parentheses, not just your numerator. `100 * (markup/costprice)`

Comment: @JNevill none of my denominators is 0

Comment: @Spinx I guess I'll have to take your word for it since you didn't include any sample data for your `costprice` column.

Comment: There is no costprice column

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql) function

```
select
   total_costprice
   ,markup
   ,case when markup=0 then 0 else 100*(markup/NULLIF(costprice,0)) END as pctmarkup
```

Comment: thanks @Cool_Br33ze works fine

Answer (score 0):

Based on your values this will work. I inserted 0 where you dont have any data - I dont know if that is true.

```
declare @myt table (item nvarchar(50),ordqty int, total_costprice numeric(18,4),totalsalesprice numeric(18,4),onhand numeric(18,4),markup numeric(18,4)
)

insert into @myt
values 


('ENG-MAN-0102',      0    ,   3852   ,  203.34   ,        2494     , 73.992    ),
('SPG-P-018'   ,      0    ,   2716   ,  1232.80  ,        473.2232 , 0         ),
('A8'          ,      0    ,   8.62   ,  9.335    ,        0        , 0.71      ),
('A136'        ,      0    ,   1621   ,  148.35   ,        518      , 0.3777    ),
('LA'          ,      1228 ,   7.68   ,  14.897   ,        0        , 7.217     ),
('ENG-DOR'     ,      1039 ,   34.94  ,  50.8166  ,        0        , 15.8766   ),
('A13-00-S'    ,      968  ,   153.64 ,  107      ,        0        , 0.9997​   )

select * ,CASE WHEN markup=0 THEN 0 ELSE 100*(markup)/total_costprice end as Pct from @myt
```

**Result**

[image]